# How to print values for two columns of a .csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am generating below data inside a for loop

> 2021-08-01 ['I', 'go', 'home']
>  2021-08-01 ['They', 'are', 'doing',
> 'great']
>  2021-08-02 ['We', 'are', 'here']
>  2021-08-02 ['You',
> 'are', 'awesome']

What I want to do is that I want to print above content to a .csv file of two columns `Date` & `Text` (Sample as below)

```
Date            Text
2021-08-01      ['I', 'go', 'home']
2021-08-01      ['They', 'are', 'doing', 'great']
2021-08-02      ['We', 'are', 'here']
2021-08-02      ['You', 'are', 'awesome']
```

```
    for key, val in res.items():
    keywords = []
    scores = []
    for index in val:
        keywords.append(index)
        scores.append(val[index])
    for i in find_clusters(keywords, scores):
        repA = list(dict.fromkeys(w for s in i for w in s.split()))
        print(key, repA)#this is where I print above values
```

Comment: Do you have the loop to generate this? Why not use pd.to_csv()?

Comment: also, realize what you are proposing is *not* .csv format.  csv=comma separated values and you have 2 notional columns not separated by commas with internal things that are...  have you considered `json`?

Comment: @Avi Thaker I gets string values so how can I use pd.to_csv()?

Comment: @AirSquid I didnt get the question?

Comment: The format you are proposing is *NOT* .csv format....  this makes it tricky to read back in, etc.  If you just want to print the data, consider a .txt file.  If you want to serialize data, consider a .json file

Comment: `CSV` means `comma separated values` (comma means `,`) but you want to use comma as part of value in one column - it will be big problem to read it later.

Comment: to get expected text in file you could even open file at start `fh = open(filename, "w")` and do `print(.... , file=fh)`

Comment: I want to make it csv or either exel file for further processing. So If I can make them to such file how to proceed? @furas

Comment: you should rather use module `csv` and function `writerow( [ key, repA] )`

Comment: @furas yes how can I do it in the implementation?

Comment: The values you have are from a file or are you generating them?

Comment: @Ishan Shishodiya I'm generating them

Comment: Then you can try appending them into a list and converting this list into a `pandas` dataframe. This would be a lot quicker. Can you share the code on how you are generating this so I can show you my method?

Comment: Why not do df = pd.DataFrame(input_list); then df.to_csv(delimiter="\t") so it would make them separated by tabs? Then reading in can also use tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get file like

```
2021-08-01 ['I', 'go', 'home']
2021-08-01 ['They', 'are', 'doing', 'great']
2021-08-02 ['We', 'are', 'here']
2021-08-02 ['You', 'are', 'awesome']
```

you can even open file at start and use it with `print()`

```
fh = open("output.txt", "w")

# ... code ...

print(key, repA, file=fh)

# ... code ...

fh.close()
```

But this file will make problem to read it.

It would be better to use module`csv` to write it

```
import csv

fh = open("output.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(fh)

writer.writerow(["Date", "Text"])

# ... code ...

writer.writerow( [key, repA] )

# ... code ...

fh.close()
```

Or you can put all in list and use `pandas` to write `csv` or `excel` (or write to some database)

```
import pandas as pd


all_rows = []

# ... code ...

all_rows.append( [key, repA] )

# ... code ...

df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows, columns=["Date", "Text"])

df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)

# or

df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: It worked!! But the output saves as below within inverted commas
2021-08-02 "['You', 'are', 'awesome']" ?

Comment: this is how CVS resolves problem with commas in data - it puts element in `" "` and when it reads row then it knows that commas inside `" "` are part of one column and they don't split it into separated columns.